# Web3.py Transaction with hash ХХХ not found

Tags: transactions, web3.py, polygon

I have a issues. I need to receive a receipt for transaction `"0x7a695820b6491b767308c45776e1da5445c7a2edac29aa14d916bda834d47c31"` on Polygon, in which the Klima Token contract was created.
But when running the code:

```
w3.eth.get_transaction_receipt("0x7a695820b6491b767308c45776e1da5445c7a2edac29aa14d916bda834d47c31")
```

Outputs:

```
Transaction with hash: '0x7a695820b6491b767308c45776e1da5445c7a2edac29aa14d916bda834d47c31' not found.
```

At the same time, there is a transaction on Polygonscan and has been confirmed for many months.
What could be the issues?

https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x7a695820b6491b767308c45776e1da5445c7a2edac29aa14d916bda834d47c31

Comment: How are you connecting to polygon? How is w3 instantiated?

Comment: @Ismael I connect like this. Everything works fine, except for some transactions, as written above.

`w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://polygon-rpc.com'))
w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only node change helped. Didn't find any other solution.

Comment: It's likely the Ethereum node you were using was corrupted or light weight.